# elixir() undefined in blade files of Lumen framework

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, lumen, laravel-elixir

I am new in Laravel. I'm trying to do some vuejs related front end stuff in my existing Lumen project (v5.1). Current `composer.json` is

```
"require": {
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "predis/predis": "~1.0",
    "illuminate/redis": "*",
    "palanik/lumen-cors":"dev-master",
    "league/fractal": "0.9.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.0"
},
```

I've introduced elixir there so that I can mix up a little bit of vue there as well. My `package.json` looks like the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
  "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
  "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
  "vue": "^2.0.1",
  "vue-loader": "^9.5.1",
  "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
  "vuex": "^2.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "jquery": "^3.1.0"
}
```

And my gulp file for converting and version js file (a single on to start) is:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.webpack('report.js');
    mix.version('js/report.js');
});
```

Now when I run gulp it compiles and creates a versioned `report.js` file in path `public/build/js/`. So in my blade file I try to load this compiled script as

```
<script src="{{ elixir('build/js/report.js') }}"></script>
```

But when I run my project it shows the following error:

> Call to undefined function elixir() (View: /var/www/html/app/resources/views/myView.blade.php)

Everything is done according to documentation I believe. Can anyone please tell me where I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: not related to your problem, but shouldnt vue be part of your dependencies and not part of dev dependencies? Arent you going to need that vue.js file when its time for production?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll change these vue related dependencies accordingly

Comment: sorry i couldnt help with the real problem, that just jumped out at me. Good luck with this one!

Comment: should the function name in the <script> be elixir() or mix() ? Not sure myself

Comment: I found `elixir()` definition [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1556b50eaae800a3727799edf4580664d2e2bb9e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L411)

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can use the code from there, and adjust it a bit...